# graphing R in org-babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ess, r, literate-programming

How can I get a graph back in my org-babel results for R code?

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :results output latex 
boxplot(islands)
#+END_SRC
```

Islands is a baked in dataset for R.

Do you do it with

```
#+resname:
```

and org-auto-load-images = T in your .emacs?

[resname example](https://eschulte.github.io/org-scraps/scraps/2009-11-20-asymptote.html)

[image: Perfect Answer]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close! Two changes:

For the R code, you'll need a few more headers:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :results output graphics :file test.png
  library("ggplot2")
  ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()
#+END_SRC
```

(Note that the headers change slightly depending on whether you want to use base R, as in your example, or something like ggplot2, as in mine. See the docs [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html#orgheadline4) for more exposition on this. TL;DR: include `output` if you want to use `ggplot2` et al.)

To display the image, you've got a couple choices:

- `org-toggle-inline-images` will switch inline image display on and off
- `org-startup-with-inline-images` is a variable which can be set in your config files (`init.el` / `.emacs.d` / whathaveyou). If non-nil, images will be shown by default on buffer load.

Also useful is `org-redisplay-inline-images`, for refreshing an image that's changed on disk if org doesn't auto-reload it.

Comment: Is there a more complicated version if I want the png in the emacs buffer and I will be exporting to html (C-c C-e h o) and pdf (C-c C-e l o) versions? Neither of those has images in the output at the moment.

Comment: Without seeing your current code, my hunch is you need to add the header arg `:exports both` to your src block. By default, only code is exported.